# Docker compose php version lower than actual

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I'm trying to do `docker-compose up -d --build` and there´s a part where I get the errors

```
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction:
#0 0.785 Installing dependencies from lock file
#0 0.787 Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
#0 0.802 Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.
#0 0.802
#0 0.802   Problem 1
#0 0.802     - doctrine/lexer is locked to version 3.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
#0 0.802     - doctrine/lexer 3.0.0 requires php ^8.1 -> your php version (8.0.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

but when I do `php --version` I have version 8.2.0 and when I run Apache I get the same result, version 8.2.0.

I've tried basically everything I've found online but nothing seems to fix the issue.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks alot for your time :)

Comment: What is your base image? Please provide a [mre] of a _Dockerfile_ reproducing your issue.

Comment: How is this problem related to Composer itself? How did you configure the images?